# Active Directory DNS server not updating

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, domain-controller

I'm having issues with an Active Directory 2008 R2 domain controller which we use as our "main" controller, as that's where we enter user, etc.  We were having problems with new logins.  Also changes were not propagating to the other domain controller. 
I traced the problem, at least partially to the DNS server on that controller.  The name of the computer didn't match the Host(A) record in the domain Forward lookup zone.

In the DNS Forward lookup zone the NS record had the correct name of the computer, but the IP address entry is empty.  The Host(A) record, shows the old name of the computer (it was changed some time ago).

I also was able to add a Host(A) record for dummy address with an IP in the subnet.  But when I try to ping it with the command **>ping dummy** , DNS can't resolve it's IP address even though I'm using a command prompt on the server with the DNS.

I also noticed that in the network setting that this server is listed second for DNS servers to try.

Testing on my Virtual Domain I have set for experiments I find that if I change the name of my Win 2008 server, I'm forced to reboot before name changes take affect, and on reboot, the DNS records are automatically updated with the new computer name.

So with my server that's having issues, why is the DNS records not updating automatically? The service is running and I can add records, but DNS doesn't seem to be able to find them.

Comment: hi maybe its not getting informed by the dhcp. however as you dobt dhow xour dhcp and dns config its hsrd to say

Comment: DHCP is not configured.  All devices are using statically configured IP addresses.  It's not an office environment.

Comment: What's the FIRST DNS server listed (since you stated that the Dc is the second in the list)?  Is it a public DNS server?  If so - that's your problem and I'll be happy to craft an answer detailing the solutio

Comment: if this isnt a office or Business Environment then your question is ouz of scope for serverfault.com please visit superuser.com